# Adobe Source Sans Pro font does not render correctly on Windows 10

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-10-preview

I've already installed the fonts locally, but it still does not work.

[image: laravel]
[image: githubio]

Comment: This is in all apps or in a specific app/browser?

Comment: @Karan, only in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the cause. Just turn off experimental DirectWrite in the flags. It is caused by the font rendering system of chrome.